# Amazon AWS Ubuntu Server Need to login with new users

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

The AWS Instance is in Ubuntu Server. I can able to login through Ubuntu Server through Ubuntu login (ubuntu@Public DNS value).

I gave the below Host Name in Putty.

```
ubuntu@ec2-54-67-100-126.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

And also created PPK file from PEM file.(The PPK file name is `devsignapi.ppk`)

I can able to login to the amazon server with these credentials. And created a user in the Ubuntu Server in the below commands.

```
   sudo adduser dev1
and set up the password also.
```

To login with `dev1@ec2-54-67-100-126.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` 
I Created the Public SSH key file from PPK file generated from Amazon Private PPK file.The PPK file name is:

```
Using username "ubuntu".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Last login: Wed Feb  4 05:40:27 2015 from 106.208.43.99
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-230:~$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-230:~$ ls
docsignapipublic.ppk
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-230:~$ cat devsignapipublic.ppk >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-230:~$ cd ~/.ssh
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-230:~/.ssh$ cat authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC7xbVAxh7d7JXLqQOtnOOh7qdZK4+ZCPLUl6hqbInjQbtuhfa2ixfVIVjxNdiOHAEh7cRF7zRBOq7jiuop9OyXdOfwhgGCYynJzvLvQB3aJat/15aFPEyNyoVldOgmNYkGZC5Q0vQK1b1TYffgnJqBMfTPtSAB0MZBwaOWdZ1vqam9o/cooo7huXVee7zqwG6hRouCU69cRTg6ZDRVTLitw41UyJPLhdwgHnDCgHoAih8O4Sx4vCjnqsYeyRqcgIvio6BOXCBjoVeTqmBCV8PazS/EsMmjvTqjrxjq/Wh1YRNFu0dLhOx6tmO3Q8bPTNlXZZYx+4FfUO2UeLOTTnFF devsignapi
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "imported-openssh-key"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC7xbVAxh7d7JXLqQOtnOOh7qdZK4+ZCPLU
l6hqbInjQbtuhfa2ixfVIVjxNdiOHAEh7cRF7zRBOq7jiuop9OyXdOfwhgGCYynJ
zvLvQB3aJat/15aFPEyNyoVldOgmNYkGZC5Q0vQK1b1TYffgnJqBMfTPtSAB0MZB
waOWdZ1vqam9o/cooo7huXVee7zqwG6hRouCU69cRTg6ZDRVTLitw41UyJPLhdwg
HnDCgHoAih8O4Sx4vCjnqsYeyRqcgIvio6BOXCBjoVeTqmBCV8PazS/EsMmjvTqj
rxjq/Wh1YRNFu0dLhOx6tmO3Q8bPTNlXZZYx+4FfUO2UeLOTTnFF
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-230:~/.ssh$ authorized_keys
```

Now i am try to login using the created User dev1. So in Putty, i gave the below Host Name

```
dev1@ec2-54-67-100-126.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

And also decsignapipublic.ppk file. But i am getting the below error.

Unable to use key file "C:\Users\Murugan\Desktop\desktop\db structure\Hubino\Amazon Web Services\devsignapipublic.ppk" (not a private key)
Using username "dev1".

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that need to be fixed here.

1. authorized_keys file only requires the public key. These start with `ssh-dsa` or `ssh-rsa`. You can have multiple keys associated to a user, one per line. In this case you added the private key to the authorized keys file. This is incorrect.
2. Each user has its own authorized_keys file in their home directory. OpenSSH requires that these files are readable only by the assigned user. If the file is missing, you can create it.
3. If you don't have the public key, you can get it using the private key file. Putty has a tool for this or you can use the ssh utilities.